# 200 error: missing username when logging in using Parse and LiveCode

Tags: parse-platform, livecode

I am trying to login to Parse through LiveCode but keep getting this error:

> {"code":200,"error":"missing username"}

I have been able to create users, even validate user's email (through the REST API in Parse) but when I try to login I keep getting an error.
I think there is something wrong with my JSON formatting or the GET call but I can't figure it out.

```
command mainLogin
 local tLoginA, tLoginJson, tReturn, tLogin

 setHeaders
 put fld "username" into tLoginA [ "username" ]
 put the cPassword of fld "password" into tLoginA [ "password" ]
 put urlEncode ( JSON_stringified ( tLoginA ) ) into tLogin
 put urldecode ( tLogin ) --testing 

 get url ( "https://api.parse.com/1/login?" & tLogin )
 put it  --testing
 put JSON_parsed ( it ) into tReturn 
 if ( tReturn [ "error" ] <> empty ) then 
      answer "Please try again: " & tReturn [ "error" ]
 end if
 if ( tReturn [ "sessionToken" ] is NOT empty ) then 
      //user logged in successfully
      put tReturn [ "sessionToken" ] into sSessionToken
      put tReturn [ "objectid" ] into sObjecteID
      answer "Welcome " && tLoginA [ "username" ]
      mainClearFields
 end if
end mainLogin
```

The functions `JSON_parsed()` and `JSON_stringified()` are from a JSON library by Andreas Rozek.

---

**Update**

I pulled this from the Parse.com REST API documentation on logging in:

> After you allow users to sign up, you need to let them log in to their account with a username and password in the future. To do this, send a GET request to the /1/login endpoint with username and password as URL-encoded parameters...

I get that conceptually but I can't get it to work.

Thanks Mark for your comment. I see that I was using the Post header handler which has the `Content-Type: application/json` added but that doesn't change much. According to the Parse.com docs the GET verb is the proper one (I changed the code to show the new header handler).

Answer (score 0):

You have a handler `setPostHeaders`, which suggests that you need to use the POST instead of the GET method. If that's true, you need to change part of your script.

```
put urlEncode ( JSON_stringified ( tLoginA ) ) into tLogin
post tLogin to url "https://api.parse.com/1/login"
put the result into rslt // check for errors if not empty
put the urlResponse into myResponse // empty if error occurred
```

Provided that the parse.com part of your script is correct, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: "send a GET request to the /1/login endpoint with username and password as URL-encoded parameters"

Try the following;

```
put "username=" & urlEncode("YourUser") & "&password=" & urlEncode("YourPass") into tLogin
get url ( "https://api.parse.com/1/login?" & tLogin )
```